# Symfony 3.4: Attempted to call an undefined method named

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony3.4, I put `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">` in the twig file and changed the PC version page to support csrf_token.
When I did the same with the SP version, the following error occurred.
Do you have any idea?
I deleted var / cache, but it didn't make sense. Also, getshopFooterMenu doesn't seem to be used in other files.

Error

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getshopFooterMenu" of class 
"__TwigTemplate_7a3846503e3cf029b2c0fa468b91304993e1ffe3af6967143083bc2ba5fa5e78".
in var/cache/dev/twig/a4/a482643be5a0726f762be6344916ca57425b8abc244bf4586931d6dc51604032.php (line 204)
```

SP_login.html.twig

```
    <article>
        <div class="login">
            <h3>ABAHOUSE<br>Shop portal store management</h3>
            <div class="content-padded">
                <form method="post" action="{{ path('app_ahi_sp_admin_sp_security_logincheck') }}" autocomplete="off" >

                    {# Add #}
                    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">

                    <span style="text-align:center;color:red;">{{ alertError | nl2br }}</span>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" class="imeOff" value="{{ last_username }}" placeholder="ID">
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="PASSWORD">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
```

PC_login.html.twig

```
    <form method="post" action="{{ path('app_ahi_sp_admin_security_logincheck') }}" autocomplete="off" >

        {# TODO I'll fix it later #}
        <table style="margin: 20px auto">
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;color:red;">{{ alertError | nl2br }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Login ID</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="username" name="_username" class="imeOff" value="{{ last_username }}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>password</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" id="password" name="_password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-signin"></i> Login</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                    <a href="{{ path("app_ahi_sp_admin_security_passwordforgot") }}">※If you forget your password</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Twig_extension1

```php
    public function getshopFooterMenu()
    {
        $context = $this->env->getGlobals();

        $blocks = array();

        ob_start();
        try {
            // line 301
            echo "    <!-- ftMenu -->
    <nav id=\"gNavi\" class=\"bar bar-tab\">
        <a class=\"tab-item active\" href=\"";
            // line 303
            echo $this->env->getExtension('routing')->getPath("ahi_sp_admin_sp_shop_default_index");
            echo "\" data-ignore=\"push\">
            <span class=\"icon icon-home\"></span><span class=\"tab-label\">Home</span>
        </a>
        <a href=\"#\" id=\"postBtn\" class=\"tab-item\" data-trigger=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modal-entryList\" data-ignore=\"push\">
            <span class=\"icon icon-compose\"></span><span class=\"tab-label\">投稿</span>
        </a>
        <a href=\"#\" id=\"searchBtn\" class=\"tab-item\" data-trigger=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modal-searchList\" data-ignore=\"push\">
            <span class=\"icon icon-search\"></span><span class=\"tab-label\">検索</span>
        </a>
        <a class=\"tab-item\" href=\"";
            // line 312
            echo $this->env->getExtension('routing')->getPath("ahi_sp_admin_sp_security_logout");
            echo "\" data-ignore=\"push\">
            <span class=\"icon icon-close\"></span><span class=\"tab-label\">ログアウト</span>
        </a>
    </nav>
    <!-- /ftMenu -->
";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            ob_end_clean();

            throw $e;
        }

        return ('' === $tmp = ob_get_clean()) ? '' : new Twig_Markup($tmp, $this->env->getCharset());
    }
```

a482643be5a0726f762be6344916ca57425b8abc244bf4586931d6dc51604032.php

```php
    public function block_body($context, array $blocks = array())
    {
        // line 28
        echo "    <header class=\"bar bar-nav am\">
        ";
        // line 29
        $this->displayBlock("BackIcon", $context, $blocks);
        echo "
        <h1 class=\"title\">";
        // line 30
        $this->displayBlock("contentTitleIcon", $context, $blocks);
        $this->displayBlock("contentTitle", $context, $blocks);
        echo "</h1>
        ";
        // line 31
        $this->displayBlock("contentBackIcon", $context, $blocks);
        echo "
        ";
        // line 33
        echo "        ";
        if ((!(isset($context["modal"]) ? $context["modal"] : null))) {
            // line 34
            echo "            <button class=\"btn btn-link btn-nav pull-right info-btn \" id=\"information-btn\" data-target=\"#modal-info\" data-trigger=\"modal\" style=\"display:none\">
                <span class=\"icon icon-info\"></span>
            </button>
        ";
        }
        // line 38
        echo "        ";
        // line 39
        echo "        ";
        $this->displayBlock("modalCloseIcon", $context, $blocks);
        echo "
    </header>

    ";
        // line 42
        if ((!(isset($context["modal"]) ? $context["modal"] : null))) {
            // line 43
            echo "
        ";
            // line 45
            echo "        ";
            echo $context["macros"]->getshopFooterMenu();
            echo "

        ";
            // line 48
            echo "        ";
            echo $context["macros"]->getarticleEntryList();
            echo "

        ";
            // line 51
            echo "        ";
            echo $this->env->getExtension('http_kernel')->renderFragment($this->env->getExtension('http_kernel')->controller("AhiSpAdminBundle:Sp/Shop/Default:notification"));
            echo "

        ";
            // line 54, Error code
            echo "        ";
            echo $context["macros"]->getarticleSearchList();
            echo "
    ";
        }
        // line 56
        echo "
    ";
        // line 57
        $this->displayBlock('contentBody', $context, $blocks);
        // line 58
        echo "
";
```

Answer (score 0):

The import destination of macros was the PC version, but it was necessary to import the SP version correctly.
Before
`{- import 'AppAhiSpAdminBundle::adminmacros.html.twig' as macros -%}`
After
`{- import 'AppAhiSpAdminBundle:Sp:adminmacros.html.twig' as macros -%}`